# How to display a blank div in my case?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to display my array in my app.

I have something like

JS

```
$scope.array1 = [' ',' ',1,2,3,4,5];
$scope.array2 = [6,7,8,9,10,' ',' '];
$scope.array3 = [12,13,14,15,16,17];
```

html

```
<div ng-repeat="a1 in array1">
    {{a1}}
</div>

<div ng-repeat="a2 in array2">
    {{a2}}
</div>

<div ng-repeat="a3 in array1">
    {{a3}}
</div>
```

I was hoping to display empty div through my ng-repeat. However, I got error

Duplicates in a repeater are not allowed. Use 'track by' expression to specify unique keys. Repeater: a1 in array1, Duplicate key: string: , Duplicate value: " "

Is there anyway I can display empty div in my case? Thanks!

Comment: your error line has the answer, try looking at the error lines carefully

Comment: I know, but I tried it before and it didn't work on my other array and I automatically assume this won't work either. Thanks for pointing out!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use this:

```
<div ng-repeat="a1 in array1 track by $index">
    {{a1}}
</div>
```

track by $index means it will track element by index not by element value.